# Can I configure non-Google Cloud resources as origin for Google Cloud CDN?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud-computing

As soon as I proceed to add a new origin for Google CDN distribution, it asks me to choose from load balancers (I would prefer not to create load balancer).

Ignoring the fact that I don't want to create a load balancer, I go ahead and create one on hopes that it would allow me to add my custom backend (an S3 bucket in this case), but even there it only allows me to add only "instance groups".

Is there any way at all that I could point this to a non-Google-Cloud origin?

Comment: Since the answer below says no, you could consider [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) or [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as CDNs that work with any origin.

Comment: Yep, but I would have been really happy if GCP had this too. (cheaper data transfers) :)

Comment: You can review [CDN Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/cdn-interconnect) to find about third party CND providers for Google Cloud Platform products. You can also submit a feature request at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud CDN has recently been updated to allow an origin outside of GCP. It does still require usage of their loadbalancer.

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/custom-origins-overview

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud CDN only works with an HTTP(s) load balancer, as described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/). Also, a backend bucket can only be a Google Cloud Storage bucket as described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing).